# Error when trying to use Google Gmail API

Tags: python, authentication, gmail-api

I'm trying to automate sending emails to a group of people.
I use credentials.json for authentication and the sample code from gmail api's site.
Error: `An error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/,<the account I used>/messages/send?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">`
Where is the problem with the authentication process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The sample code from the [Gmail API quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) contains the scope `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'`

However, for [sending messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send) you need one of the following scopes:

- https://mail.google.com/
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose

Change the scope in your code to one of the listed ones and delete your token file to trigger new authorization flow when running your code with the new scope.